# get screen size in python

Tags: python, monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python)

I was wondering if there was a way to get the screen size from a python script.

**Similar Questions:**

[Getting monitor size in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662857/getting-monitor-size-in-python)

This question tells you how to get it through pygame. Is there a way to do it with just python? I need the scripts to run on several Unix-based operating system.

Comment: Is your script a console (text mode) program, or a GUI program? How are you drawing things to the screen? If you're using a library like `curses`, then use the facilities of that library.

Comment: I use matplotlib to graph stuff. I just want to make the figure size appropriate so that it takes up the full screen. I just need to find a way to get the screen size to make the figure the appropriate size

Comment: One way might be to create the image with some reasonable resolution like 1280x1024, then ask whatever image viewer you're using to scale it to the actual screen size.

Comment: seems like a dup to me. I did not see that question. I still have a question... I do have one Mac OS X machine. Where can I download/install AppKit?

Answer (score 3):

I stole this from [Finding the workspace size (screen size less the taskbar) using GTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502282/finding-the-workspace-size-screen-size-less-the-taskbar-using-gtk)

```
import gtk, pygtk

window = gtk.Window()
screen = window.get_screen()
print "width = " + str(screen.get_width()) + ", height = " + str(screen.get_height())
```

Just to let you know, if you have multiple monitors the screen's size will be all of those monitors together.